# Comment form in django didn't save the new comments

Tags: python, django

I've created a new form for comments the articles on a website. When I add the new comment from django admin everything works ok, but when I try to add the new comment directly from detail page nothings happen and I'am redirecting to the page with list of articles.
here are my files
models.py:

```
class Komentarz(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Wpisy, related_name="komentarze", verbose_name="Komentarze do artykułu", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80, verbose_name="Imię")
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="Email")
    content = models.TextField(verbose_name="Treść komentarza")
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Utworzono", auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Aktywny?", default=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created_date',)
        verbose_name="Komentarz"
        verbose_name_plural="Komentarze"

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Komentarz dodany przez {} dla strony {}'.format(self.name, self.post)
```

vies.py with the function of details

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Wpisy, Komentarz
from .forms import KomentarzeForma
....
def detale_bajki(request, slug, ):
    detale_bajki = get_object_or_404(Wpisy, slug=slug)
    komentarze = detale_bajki.komentarze.filter(active=True)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formularz_komentarza = KomentarzeForma(data=request.POST)
        if formularz_komentarza.is_valid():
            nowy_komentarz = formularz_komentarza.save(commit=False)
            nowy_komentarz.detale_bajki = detale_bajki
            nowy_komentarz.save()
    else:
        formularz_komentarza = KomentarzeForma()
        return render(request, 'bajki/detale_bajki.html', {'detale_bajki': detale_bajki, 'komentarze': komentarze, 'formularz_komentarza': formularz_komentarza})
```

forms.py

```
from .models import Komentarz
from django import forms


class KomentarzeForma(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Komentarz
        fields = ('name', 'email', 'content')
```

and detail.html

```
...
                {% with komentarze.count as total_komentarze %}
                <h2>
                {{ total_komentarze }} komentarz{{ total_komentarze|pluralize:"y" }}
                </h2>
                {% endwith %}

                {% for komentarz in komentarze %}
                Komentarz dodany przez <strong>{{komentarz.name}}</strong>
                {{komentarz.created_date}}
                <p>
                {{ komentarz.content|linebreaks }}<br>
                {% empty %}
                <p>Nie dodano jeszcze żadnych komentarzy</p>
                {% endfor %}

                {% if nowy_komentarz %}
                <h2>Twój komentarz został dodany</h2>
                {% else %}
                <h2>Dodaj nowy komentarz</h2>
                <form action="." method="post">
                {{formularz_komentarza.as_p}}
                {% csrf_token %}
                <p><input type="submit" value="Dodaj komentarz"></p>
                </form>
                {% endif %}
```

clas Wpisy in models.py

```
class Wpisy(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=400, verbose_name="Tytuł")
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=400,verbose_name="Przyjazny adres url")
    content = models.TextField()
    status_audio = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Czy dostępny będzie plik audio?")
    audio_file = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/',verbose_name="Plik audio")
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Data utworzenia")
    category = models.ForeignKey(Kategorie, verbose_name="Kategoria", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name="Wpis"
        verbose_name_plural="Wpisy"


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: Your `detale_bajki` view isn't returning a response after calling `nowy_komentarz.save()`. Check your indentation. Please show your urls as well.

Comment: In you `detail.html` the form does not pass the `slug` which is an argument in `views.detale_bajki`.

Answer (score 1):

Your url pattern is

```
path('bajki/<slug>', views.detale_bajki, name='detale_bajki')
```

Note that it doesn't have a trailing slash. Your form's action is `"."`

```
<form action="." method="post">
```

That means you are submitting to `/bajki/`, which is the wrong URL.

You could fix this by adding a trailing slash to the url (which is common in Django URLs)

```
path('bajki/<slug>/', views.detale_bajki, name='detale_bajki')
```

Or you could change the form action to `""` instead of `"."`. In the comments it looks like you fixed the issue by changing the form action to `{{ detale_bajki.slug }}`.

However these changes to the form action are fragile, and could break if you change your URL patterns again. The best approach is to use the `{% url %}` tag to reverse the correct URL.

```
<form action="{% url 'detale_bajki' detale_bajki.slug %}" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out:

```
nowy_komentarz.post = detale_bajki
...
return render(request, 'html page', {'key': 'what you want to return to your context'}) # don't fornget to add some return to your view.
```

Comment: I have try to change how You wrote. But still nothing :(

Comment: Sorry Eliakim but I think I don't understand You. What does it mean "im" ?

Comment: tbh I'm trying to guess what's the solution. You can debug it by yourself using pdb:

<!-- language: Python -->

    # at the start of the view
    import pdb
    pdb.set_trace()

Take a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html

I bet that your form is not passing by is_valid() method.

Comment: Ok i added line import pdb; pdb.set_trace()and now in console I have only this: > c:\projekty\public_python\bajki\views.py(2)<module>()
-> from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
(Pdb). How to check the errors? Of course  localhost stop working when I implement pdb

Comment: Just presses 'n' and 'enter' for every line and check in which line your code breaks. It's just to visualize the flow of your code.

Comment: Eliakin I have a lots of lines and I think Iam too amateur to guest what could can happen

Comment: It's ok, can you share the Wpisy model, then I can run it on my computer.

Comment: class Wpisy(models.Model):
 title = models.CharField(max_length=400, verbose_name="Tytuł")
 slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=400,verbose_name="Przyjazny adres url")
 content = models.TextField()
 status_audio = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Czy dostępny będzie plik audio?")
 audio_file = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/',verbose_name="Plik audio")
 created_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Data utworzenia")
 category = models.ForeignKey(Kategorie, verbose_name="Kategoria", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

Comment: class Meta:
  verbose_name="Wpis"
  verbose_name_plural="Wpisy"


 def __str__(self):
  return self.title

Comment: I had to split it to 2 parts :)

Comment: and this is from my console: [24/Jan/2018 20:13:30] "GET /bajki/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1220
[24/Jan/2018 20:13:32] "GET /bajki/bardzo-ciekawy-ptaszek HTTP/1.1" 200 1595
[24/Jan/2018 20:13:51] "POST /bajki/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1220
[24/Jan/2018 20:13:53] "GET /bajki/bardzo-ciekawy-ptaszek HTTP/1.1" 200 1595
[24/Jan/2018 20:14:46] "POST /bajki/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1220
[24/Jan/2018 20:14:47] "GET /bajki/bardzo-ciekawy-ptaszek HTTP/1.1" 200 1595

Comment: Eliakin ! Eureka !! I found a bug.... In detale_bajki.html i had <form action="." method="post"> but i change it to <form action="{{detale_bajki.slug}}" method="post"> and its working !!!